# Is there a way to prevent culling a line when using an orthographic camera?

Tags: three.js

When using an orthographic camera I can't see the back side of my circle when it is angled.

[image]

It's as though the circle is being treated as a disc with a face that is blocking the view of where I expect to see the circle. Is there any way to use the orthographic camera but have not do any culling at all or at the very least not do any culling on this circle?

Do a rotate on this example to see what I'm saying:

```js
// ------------------------------------------------
// BASIC SETUP
// ------------------------------------------------

// hard code canvas dimensions
const scale = 2;
const canvasHeight = 350 * scale;
const canvasWidth = 350 * scale;

// Create an empty scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create a basic perspective camera
//var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, canvasWidth/canvasHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( canvasWidth / - 2, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2, canvasHeight / - 2, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 4;

// Create a renderer with Antialiasing
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

// Configure renderer clear color
renderer.setClearColor("#C3C3C3");

// Configure renderer size
renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

// Append Renderer to DOM
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.update();
setTimeout(function() {
  controls.reset();
}, 5000)

// ------------------------------------------------
// FUN STARTS HERE
// ------------------------------------------------

// Render Loop
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( render );

  //cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  controls.update();

  // Render the scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

//  console.log(visibleWidthAtZDepth(camera,))
};
render();

function drawCircle()
{
    let radius   = canvasWidth / 2 - 5,
      segments = 64,
      material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
      geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );

    geometry.vertices.shift();

    scene.add( new THREE.LineLoop( geometry, material ) );
}
drawCircle();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<style>
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="bolt-hole-calculator.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your camera further away from the origin. You are encountering the circle intersecting the near plane, because the camera is only 4 units from the origin, and the circle radius is much larger than that.

```js
// ------------------------------------------------
// BASIC SETUP
// ------------------------------------------------

// hard code canvas dimensions
const scale = 2;
const canvasHeight = 350 * scale;
const canvasWidth = 350 * scale;

// Create an empty scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Create a basic perspective camera
//var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, canvasWidth/canvasHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(canvasWidth / -2, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2, canvasHeight / -2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 500;

// Create a renderer with Antialiasing
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});

// Configure renderer clear color
renderer.setClearColor("#C3C3C3");

// Configure renderer size
renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

// Append Renderer to DOM
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.update();
setTimeout(function() {
  controls.reset();
}, 5000)

// ------------------------------------------------
// FUN STARTS HERE
// ------------------------------------------------

// Render Loop
var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  //cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

  controls.update();

  // Render the scene
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  //  console.log(visibleWidthAtZDepth(camera,))
};
render();

function drawCircle() {
  let radius = canvasWidth / 2 - 5,
    segments = 64,
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x0000ff
    }),
    geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments);

  geometry.vertices.shift();

  scene.add(new THREE.LineLoop(geometry, material));
}
drawCircle();

// Do a rotate on this example to see what I 'm saying:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
</body>
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="bolt-hole-calculator.js"></script>

</html>
```